# Couchdb database name

Tags: couchdb

I don't fully get the restrictions for database names on couchdb, when I try to create a name like `!abcdef/user-context-81a5c7e396` I get the error

> Create database failed: Name: '!abcdef/user-context-81a5c7e396'. Only
>   lowercase characters (a-z), digits (0-9), and any of the characters _,
>   $, (, ), +, -, and / are allowed. Must begin with a letter.

and pretty much it is because of the exclamation mark at the beginning, but I had no problem creating the database `!abcdef/_users`, so is something special about the `_users`?

I could remove the exclamation mark but this is from a project with many references to that name.

I'm using couchdb 2.2.0 and this behavior happened using curl and Fauxton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to create the `!abcdef/_users` database due to a [bug](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1644).  So the fact that `!abcdef/user-context-81a5c7e396` is failing is actually correct.

The bug has now been fixed, so this behavior should be corrected in CouchDB 2.3.0.